# How to have cited references appear as numbers

Tags: numbering, citing

What is the simple way of having cited references appear as numbers?

For example I want `\cite{author_x}` result in **[1]** in the rendered text.

My references.bib file contains entries as follows

```
@incollection{parker2016multiple,
  title={Multi robot systems},
  author={Parker, Lynne E and Rus, Daniela and Sukhatme, Gaurav S},
  booktitle={Springer Handbook of Robotics},
  pages={1335--1384},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You might want to use `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{parker2016multiple}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]
or this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{parker2016multiple}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that results in the following "package biblatex error: \bibliographystyle invalid"

Comment: @Employee, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, however, that still not works (neither of the two solutions). I should note that I am using a Latex template, maybe that is what is causing the issue. I was assuming this was going to be something simple

Comment: @Employee, it's hard to help without a more specific example.

Comment: these are my packages: \usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

Comment: And maybe this is of interest as well - \def\@importHarvard {
    \RequirePackage[
        defernumbers=true,
        backend=biber,
        bibencoding=utf8,
        natbib=true,
        hyperref=true,
        backref=true,
        urldate=long,
        style=authoryear,
        citestyle=authoryear,
        sorting=nyt
    ]{biblatex}
}

Comment: @Employee, please try to come up with a compilable example (a text file that starts with \documentclass and ends with \end{document}) that illustrates your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127637/discussion-between-employee-and-modnar).